# How to determine which working day of the month today is?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Using Google Sheets, I need to know what the numeric working day of today is.  Somehow I'm just missing something here.
I can already easily determine the number of working days remaining, with

```
=NETWORKDAYS(today(),eomonth(today(),0)
```

but how do I figure out that today (October 1) for example, is day 1, Friday will be day 4, Monday will be day 5, etc.?

Comment: Is `=day(today())` what you're looking for ?

Comment: No, I need the work day.

Comment: What is the problem with `=DAY(TODAY())` suggested on a previous comment?

Comment: It will give me the day of today including weekends.  I need the work day.  So Friday would be 4, next Monday would be 5 (not 7), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general formula as you asked is:

```
=((NETWORKDAYS(today(),eomonth(today(),-1)))*-1)-1
```

Using fixed values for today `"02/10/2019"` for dates the above formula would be:

```
=NETWORKDAYS("30/09/2019","02/10/2019")
```

We use `eomonth(today(),-1)`, so we take as our starting date the last day of the previous month.
We multiply the whole formula by `-1` because we get a negative result.

---

Please have a go and try out the formula on this [TEST spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pLe_0oc_etxlyWVxB9DZrwLyYg8boVqu0k1VpKr-dOo/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Aha... this appears to be exactly what I was trying to come up with.  I'll live with it for a bit and mark this as correct if I can't break it.  Thank you!

Comment: _"I'll live with it for a bit and mark this as correct if I can't break it"_.  It won't. Please have a go at the test spreadsheet I linked.